# How to remove unresolved packages (youtube-to-mp3 app)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I am aware that it's a common problem but i am quite new with linux systems and I would like to know how to exactly fix my problem.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

youtube-to-mp3: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) ale 2.19-0ubuntu6.4 is to be installed
                Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) ale 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt4-declarative (>= 4:4.7.0~rc1) ale 4:4.8.5+git192->g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.6.1) ale 4:4.8.5+git192->g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) ale 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg->2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) ale 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg->2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) ale 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
                Depends: libav-tools (>= 4:0.8.6-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ale 7:2.5->0ppa1~trusty is to be installed
                Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8.6ubuntu0.12.04.1) but will not be installed
                Depends: libmp3lame0 (>= 3.99.3+repack1-1) ale 3.99.5+repack1->3ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

I know that I need somehow delete some of those libraries but I don't know which and how.

Would be really nice if you guys could help. The error appeared when I stopped the installation process of one of the applications because it got stuck.

Comment: How did you try to install `youtube-to-mp3`?

Comment: Via Ubuntu Software Centrum app, but as I have written - the installation process got stuck so i had to restart it and then the error occured. I have also tried updating and upgrading using 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

I have tried:
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install -f

None of the above worked.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: 14.04 with gnome 3.12 (if it matters)

Comment: What happens if you try the following: http://www.mediahuman.com/repository.html

Comment: Thank you very much @jmunsch, it worked perfectly :) Problem solved.

Comment: @Zwierzak it would be great if you could add the steps that you followed as an answer to your own question. In case that page gets moved someplace else in the future. :D glad it worked.

Comment: @jmunsch it's done :) Hope ppl with same problem will solve their issue thanks to this. Thanks once again.

Comment: Awesome. I see that you edited your question. Just so you know, you can also answer your own question. At the bottom of the page here.

Answer (score 1):

To remove unresolved packages take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Here is how I installed youtube-to-mp3.  Download your preferred architecture [32bit](http://www.mediahuman.com/download/YouTubeToMP3.i386.deb) or [64bit](http://www.mediahuman.com/download/YouTubeToMP3.amd64.deb).

Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded, probably the downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

Or you can use [Gdebi](https://launchpad.net/gdebi) to install it.

This will install the latest version (3.6) of youtube-to-mp3

Answer (score 0):

*The OP posted this solution as an edit (reproduced here with minor copy editing).*

> First I tried to type in the terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get clean
> sudo apt-get autoclean
> sudo apt-get install -f
> ```
>
> This didn't work. Then I tried
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> ```
>
> which also didn't work.
>
> Finally thanks to kindness of people here this code worked:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository 'http://www.mediahuman.com/packages/ubuntu'
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys D808832C7D19F1F3
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install youtube-to-mp3
> ```